# Run Python script from PostgreSQL function

Tags: python, database, postgresql, triggers, postgresql-triggers

I'm facing a "little" problem regarding executing a Python script every time is an update or insert action on the PostgreSQL table.

This script will extract and write to a file updated or inserted data.

Environment data: [Ubuntu 18.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_18.04_LTS_.28Bionic_Beaver.29) (Bionic Beaver), PostgreSQL 10, and Python 3.6

```
SELECT * FROM pg_available_extensions
WHERE name LIKE '%python%' ORDER BY name;
```

And output

| name | default_version | installed_version | comment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| hstore_plpython2u | 1.0 |  | transform between hstore and plpython2u |
| hstore_plpythonu | 1.0 |  | transform between hstore and plpythonu |
| ltree_plpython2u | 1.0 |  | transform between ltree and plpython2u |
| ltree_plpythonu | 1.0 |  | transform between ltree and plpythonu |
| plpython2u | 1.0 |  | PL/Python2U untrusted procedural language |
| plpythonu | 1.0 | 1.0 | PL/PythonU untrusted procedural language |

**I've created a PostgreSQL function** (I hope it to be ok after all documentation readings)

```
CREATE FUNCTION getSomeData()
RETURNS trigger
AS $$
begin
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['/usr/bin/python3', '/some_folder/some_sub_folder/get_data.py'])
end;
$$
LANGUAGE plpythonu;
```

**After this, create trigger**

```
CREATE TRIGGER executePython
AFTER INSERT ON mytable
EXECUTE PROCEDURE getSomeData();
```

Nothing happens if I'm making any insert or update.

As an additional precaution, I did the following test

```
sudo -u postgres python3 /some_folder/some_sub_folder/get_data.py
```

and got this output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/some_folder/some_sub_folder/get_data.py", line 4, in <module>
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
ImportError: No module named sqlalchemy
```

I have installed SQLAlchemy globally and now my script runs as expected with the *postgres* user, but it does not trigger.

```
apt install python3-sqlalchemy
```

Comment: when you execute this as your usual user, do you execute it with the global python3, or is there a chance, you have venv or other environment loaded and your usual user python3 executable is alias to your venv, where you locally installed SQLAlchemy? you could try to execute by /path/to/your/environment/with/sqlalchemy/installed/bin/python3 or installing SQLAlchemy globally so your /usr/bin/python3 has access to it.

Comment: like if you don't mind using global libraries, apt install python3-sqlalchemy (but would suggest virtual environment instead)

Comment: I have installed  python3-sqlalchemy  global and my script run with postgres user. Hope to solve the trigger part now.

Comment: @Georgian I've created a community wiki from your answer - feel free to add details to it as you see fit once you have the privilege (you need 27 more rep for it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pointer to the solution provided by [bathman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7747960/bathman):

> when you execute this as your usual user, do you execute it with the global python3, or is there a chance, you have venv or other environment loaded and your usual user python3 executable is an alias to your venv, where you locally installed SQLAlchemy? you could try to execute by /path/to/your/environment/with/sqlalchemy/installed/bin/python3 or installing SQLAlchemy globally so your /usr/bin/python3 has access to it.

The solution:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION getSomeData()
RETURNS trigger
AS $$
begin
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['/path/to/your/virtual/environment/bin/python3', '/some_folder/some_sub_folder/get_data.py'])
end;
$$ 
LANGUAGE plpythonu;
```