# Is there any way to execute Python script via PostgreSQL function?

Tags: python, postgresql

I have python script saved as a text file named `test.py` on my Desktop.

I need to execute that script using PostgreSQL.

Currently I am trying to create PostgreSQL function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION database.test()
RETURNS VOID
AS $$
py /C:/Users/User1/Desktop/test.py
$$ LANGUAGE plpython3u
```

That gives me an error:

```
ERROR:  SyntaxError: invalid syntax (<string>, line 3)could not compile PL/Python function "test" 

ERROR:  could not compile PL/Python function "test"
SQL state: 38000
Detail: SyntaxError: invalid syntax (<string>, line 3)
```

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd


db_config = {'user': '******', 
    'pwd': '*******',
    'host': '*******',
    'port': ****,
    'db': '*******'} 

connection_string = 'postgresql://{}:{}@{}:{}/{}'.format(db_config['user'],
    db_config['pwd'],
    db_config['host'],
    db_config['port'],
    db_config['db'])

engine = create_engine(connection_string) 

test_df = pd.DataFrame(index=[0,1], columns= ['A', 'B'], data = 0)


test_df\
.to_sql(
    'test_2',
    schema='database',
    con=engine,
    if_exists='replace',
    index=False
)
```

Could someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run Python script from PostgreSQL function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61541532/run-python-script-from-postgresql-function)

Comment: Would you paste the python script `test.py` in the question as well?

Comment: Do you have the appropriate extension installed? See [Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpython.html).

Comment: @MiH yeah, posted it

Comment: @Belayer, Yeah. Installed `plpython3u`